# Expediency of creating separate table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

[image]

Hello. There is the table "Video" which defines video's features like: name, actor, date or release etc, so it's kinda user's info about a video, but what about location of a file? It's an information about location on a server, and it seems to me that it must be a separate table,because it's another type of data, another entity. Am I right? I would be sure that I have to create separate table, if there were more than one column in the table 'vidlocation', but for know I don't know what's the extra info about location can be needed.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

Your design looks OK to me.

You have a one-to-one relation between a video and its file : each video has a file, and each file belongs to a unique video. The usual way to store one-to-one relationship is to both values in the same table record.

As opposite, **if** you were in a situation, where each video may have several files (like : part 1, part 2, etc), then that would be a *one (video) to many (files)* relationship. You would create a separate table to store that relation, with a foreign key to the `video` table.